# How to return to previous activity when in a thread

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Basically from the MainActivity, I start a new activity called GameManagerAct. In GameManagerAct, I set my content view as a GameManager, which is just a class that contains a thread. As it has a thread, it is stuck in my GameManager object. When I reach a point in the GameManager object where I want to return to the previous activity (MainActivity), how would I do this? Since it is just a class and not an Activity, it doesn't have access to the finish() command for GameManagerAct.

I've tried moving the code from the GameManager object into the GameManagerAct, but this doesn't work.

// In MainActivity.java

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameManagerAct.class));
```

// In GameManagerAct.java

```
GameManager gm = new GameManager(this);
setContentView(gm);
```

// In GameManager.java

```
else if (quitRect.contains(movePointX, movePointY)) {
    // ends GameManagerAct activity and returns back the MainActivity
}
```

I want the setContentView to return back to the one for MainActivity. Currently, nothing happens cause I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you should make interface to access your view (activity) from your GameManager class, and when your work finish it call the method of your interface, in that interface method you can finish the activity. or you can use observable design pattern too.

```
interface GameInterface{
 void workDone();
}
```

in your activity implement this

```
GameManagerAct implement GameInterface{
```

and overrite it like:

```
void workDone(){
this.finish();
}
```

pass it to GameManager classs.
and in it use the method when work done.

```
interfaceObject.workDone();
```